# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: sockets, quickfix, apache-mina

The application uses [quickfixj](http://www.quickfixj.org) library, which uses [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/).
This application keeps a socket connection to a remote host.

Suddenly we get the following error:

```
[SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0]   - ERROR quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler  - socket exception (/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx is the remote address.

What may be causing the connection drop? The remote host? My OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection was being dropped by some switch because the machine bandwidth was too high (above the limit)

Comment: Where would we find out what the machine bandwidth is?

Answer (score 0):

Most firewalls kill an idle connection after some time.

Comment: The application keeps trying to reconnect, but after this error with no success.