# C# Game Server: An established connection was aborted

Tags: c#

**I have read all the  other questions that are the same error as mine and they do NOT apply to my situation.**

Hello. Recently I have been receiving a very weird error in my Game Server:

```
  14:44:18 - Error sending message to socket: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
  14:44:18 - System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Hariak_Emulator.Emulator.Base.Game.Habbo.Players.Players.GameClient.SendData(Byte[] data) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\EmuDev17\Hariak Emulator\Hariak Emulator\Emulator\Base\Game\Habbo\Players\Players\PlayerConnection.cs:line 264 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Hariak_Emulator.Emulator.Base.Game.Habbo.Players.Players.GameClient.SendData(Byte[] data) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\EmuDev17\Hariak Emulator\Hariak Emulator\Emulator\Base\Game\Habbo\Players\Players\PlayerConnection.cs:line 264
```

Why is this, can someone help?
Here is the code it happens on (line 264 PlayerConnection):

```
internal void SendData(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, OnSend, null);
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        Logger.Error("Error sending message to socket: " + socketException.Message);
        Logger.Error(socketException);

        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the port number of this server ?

Comment: My port is 30000 (30,000 formatted).

Comment: Check that your firewall is not blocking this port : http://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it shouldn't block it if I am running it on 127.0.0.1 (localhost), which I am?

Comment: Another post suggests there is a firewall timeout : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477003/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine?rq=1